# jQuery Click anchor tag prevent page from scrolling to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, scroll, preventdefault

I'm doing page transitions with jQuery by fading out content and fading it back in when the page loads but my problem is when I click my link and call my click function and redirecting the page it loads at the the top of the page. Is there a way I can prevent this behavior? Here is my click function for my page transition, thanks in advance for any help!

**LINK**

```
<a href="../categories/categories.php"></a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".content").fadeIn(750);

$("a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    linkLocation = this.href;
    $(".content").fadeOut(500, redirectPage);  
});

function redirectPage() {
    window.location = linkLocation;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide markup, it would be great if you create new fiddle to see how it works.

Comment: Sounds like you need to style your markup. `javascript` is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Good solution : Use history api with hashbangs fallback**

**Bad solution:**
as an easy hack you can capture the current scroll position with

```
    $(".content").fadeIn(750);
    var offset = window.location.href.match(/offset=(\d+)/)
    if(offset){
       $(document).scrollTop(offset[1])
    }
    $("a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href + "?offset="+$(document).scrollTop();//pay 
//special attentions to this line will work only for a link without get parameters. 
        $(".content").fadeOut(500, redirectPage);  
    });

    function redirectPage() {
        window.location = linkLocation;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll look int doing it with history api and hashbangs, but thats a good little hack also thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
event.preventDefault();
linkLocation = this.href;
```

Thanks to the Team,
please kindly put this above two lines after the click function start
That will help you to make the scroll off.